Laravel Clear Text Traffic Enabled
They communicated this with the following information that I had pentest done for the security check;

User credentials are transmitting in plain text manner in Login Screen / POST request
Use encryption algorithms and cryptographic techniques to safeguard sensitive information, such as user
credentials, personal data, and financial records

And when I check, when I look at the Network > Headers field in the area where I login in my Laravel project, the login information appears as in the attachment below. How can I prevent this? I did not find a direct result, does anyone have any information?
enter image description here
I couldn't test it clearly because I couldn't find anything directly related to it, but I enabled HTTPS access, not HTTP, and some header security protocols, but it didn't work.

Who is "they"? What do you mean by" it didn't work"?

There is no problem since it is only displayed in your browser. It's the same no matter what you use other than Laravel.
